# How do I use TreeView with my Tree Datastructure? C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, tree

I have a Tree and load it recursively into my TreeView on my form. The problem is, I do not know how to find out which object in my Tree that I am selected on when I select a node in my TreeView. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `TreeNode`'s `Tag` property to the corresponding instance from your object model.

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeView` nodes (`TreeNodes`) have properties like `Level`, `Tag`, `Text` etc. The `Level` property lets you identify in which level is your `TreeNode` in the `TreeView` and the `Tag` and `Text` properties may let you identify your node uniquely. You may also add same kind of properties to your Tree too and thus you may compare them relevantly and do the conversion you require...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique id for each record you can assign that id as the [TreeNode.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx). [TreeNode.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) is another option.